# Adding a watermark to a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, watermark

Is it possible to have a watermark background for a listview control in Android? Basically I want a stationary background image with a listview on top of the image. When I scroll, I want the listview to scroll like normal, but the image stay stationary. Since there doesn't seem to be any z-order in Android, I'm wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `ListView.setBackgroundResource(int resId)`?

Or for the whole screen use...

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(int resId)
```

You'll need to use `setCacheColorHint(0)` to prevent 'blackouts' when scrolling the list though.